# getting empty square bracket on scrapy shell

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am getting empty square bracket for this xpath  `response.xpath( "//div[@class='c16H9d']").extract()`

here is url https://www.daraz.com.bd/audio/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2.2.49c74591NNpWDU

my xpath is not wrong then why I am getting this empty square bracket?

```
>>>scrapy shell "https://www.daraz.com.bd/audio/?spm=a2a0e.home.cate_2.2.49c74591NNpWDU"
>>>response.xpath( "//div[@class='c16H9d']").extract()
>>>[]
```

Comment: there is no such class `c16H9d` in the response element. What do you really want to scrape?

Comment: I posted solution below for you that should give you the data you want. If you have success please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your using scrapy shell and yes indeed that class does exist as the first item. However, if you look at the full HTML you will see this tag

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
```

This appears to contain the JSON that is used to populate the front end of the page. So you could do something like this and then import the json and use json loads to load it into a python object.

```
response.css('script::text').extract()[-1]
```

The last script elements text contains all the json for the product list of the page.

```
import json
data = json.loads(response.css('script::text').extract()[-1])
item_list = data['itemListElement']
for each in item_list:
    print(each['name'], each['price'])
```

Comment: no problem. always look at the full response text. i've seen several cases like this where they load the json into the page which i find really weird. i thought it defeats the purpose of having a front end system like that...